# MFC multibyte support

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I got a build error MSB8031 and I was redirected [to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/mfc/mfc-mbcs-dll-add-on?view=vs-2019) where it says

> The Unicode and MBCS MFC DLLs are installed with the Desktop development with C++ workload when you select MFC and ATL support from the Optional Components pane.

I went there by going to the contral panel / programs and features, using "change" on the Visual Studio 2017 entry.

Since the entry "MFC and ATL support" did not exist, I followed the next advice:

> If your installation does not include these components, navigate to the File | New Projects dialog and click the Open Visual Studio Installer link.

[image: Screenshot]

It seems to open the exact same window and there is no entry called "MFC and ATL support".

[image: Screenshot]

**How do I get multibyte support in VS 2017, version 15.9.12?**

Note that there is both "Visual C++ ATL for x86 and x64" and "Visual C++ MFC for x86 and x64" already checked, if that was meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These steps apply for Visual Studio 2017. If there are Visual Studio 2013 projects in the solution, opened with VS2017, you may see this:

[image: Screenshot]

In that case, you have to install Multibyte Support for Visual Studio 2013, not 2017.